# Насколько надёжен данный способ авторизации

Tags: php

"Сайт крутится" на одной из машин в локальной сейти. Пользователи - не слишком многочисленные работники лаборатории (до 20 человек). Использую HTTP-аутентификация: для каждого пользователя создан пользователь mysql с разграничением прав и т.п. А также имеется запись в базе данных о каждом пользователе.

Может кто подскажет, что с безопасностью и т.п., что улучшить? Код ниже и на [gist](https://gist.github.com/autumnrustle/4b44a681523c330cc60e9c22d051fde6)

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {    

    $db_hostname = 'localhost';
    $db_database = 'lg4';
    $db_username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $db_password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    //Пробуем подключиться к БД
    try {
        $connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'], $_SERVER);
        mes ("Что-то пошло не так. Возможно, вы ввели пароль с ошибкой. Или произошла другая ошибка. Попробуйте войти ещё раз.<br><a href='../../'>Повторить попытку</a>");
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        exit();
    }

    //Устанавливаем кодировку и timezone
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

    //Получаем данные о пользователе из БД
    $username=fix($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $connection);
    $query = "SELECT staff.id_staff, staff.staff_name FROM staff WHERE staff.username = '${username}'";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) die($connection->error);
    $myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    //Стартуем сеесию и сохраняем данные пользователя
    session_start();
    ini_set('session.save_path', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'../sessions/');
    $_SESSION['session_username'] = $myrow['staff_name'];
    $_SESSION['id_staff'] = $myrow['id_staff'];

} else {

    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    mes ("Для работы с базой данных вы должны ввести логин и пароль.<br><a href='../../'>Войти в базу данных</a>");
    die();

}

//Функция очистки строки
function fix($var, $connection) {
    $var=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $var);
    $var=trim($var); //удаляем лишние пробелы в начале и конце строки.
    return $var;
}

//Функция выводит на весь экран сообщение
function mes($str) {
    echo "
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
            <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
            <title>БД - Регистрация</title>
            <link rel='icon' href='favicon.png' type='image/x-icon' />
            <style>
                body {
                    font-size:22px;
                    text-align:center;
                    margin-top: 10%;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            ${str}
        </body>
        </html>
    ";
}

//Выход из БД
if (isset($_GET['exit'])) {
    $var=$_GET['exit'];
    if ($var==1 or $var==2) {
        session_unset ();
        session_destroy ();
        $connection->close();
        unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'], $_SERVER);
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        mes ("Вы успешно вышли из базы данных<br><a href='../../'>Войти в базу данных</a>");
        exit();
    }
}

//Оставляем соединение открытым
```

Comment: basic auth гоняет данные в открытом виде, нельзя так

Comment: @etki так у меня https там с сертификатом. Всё равно в открытом виде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для 20 человек в локалке, думаю, все норм. Можно конечно еще сделать проверку на количество попыток авторизации, т.е., например, еще табличку, куда записывать количество попыток авторизации того или иного клиента и, если будет больше n-ого кол-ва раз за минуту, то делать пользователю блок на пару минут, чтобы пароли не подбирали.

Comment: а подходит ли написанная функция fix() для предотвращения sql-инъекций?

Comment: да конечно подходит

Comment: @n.osennij, сначала уж trim() делайте, а только потом mysqli_real_escape_string().